# OSX: Setting Enthought python path in .bash_profile results in weird terminal behavior

Tags: python, macos, bash, terminal, enthought

I followed the [knowledge base](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-User-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-) on adding this to the .bash_profile

```
PATH="~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin"
export PATH
```

When I then restart the Terminal, a lot of functions do not work anymore:

```
X:~ excuvator$ ls
-bash: ls: command not found
X:~ excuvator$ security
-bash: security: command not found
X:~ excuvator$ sudo
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

However, enpkg and cd still seem to be callable. If I remove that part, stuff works again. Does anyone have any insight to what is happening? I just want to get enpkg running...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reset `PATH`, rather than adding to it, so `bash` doesn't know any place to look for commands other than the single directory you specified. Instead, use one of

```
PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin
```

or

```
PATH=~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:$PATH
```

Which of the two assignments you use depends on whether whether you want the new directory to be the first or last place the shell looks for a named command.

`enpkg` actually *is* in that directory, and `cd` is a shell built-in command, not an external program, so no path lookup is involved.